# Is there a function similar to np.random.choice that has a higher probability of choosing the lower values in the probability distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have an array of objects with a corresponding probability for each, say

```
sample = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
probability = [0.1, 0.15, 0.6, 0.05, 0.03, 0.07]
```

For most functions in my class this is perfect to use with np.random.choice as I want to select the values with the highest percentage chance.

On one of the functions though, I need it to be biased to the values with a lower probability (i.e. more likely to pick e and d in the sample than c).

Is there a function that can do this or do I need to consider converting the probability to some inverse probability like

```
inverse_probability = [(1-x) for x in probability]
inverse_probability = [x/sum(inverse_probability) for x in probability]
```

and then use this in the np.random.choice function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds interesting. Do you have some more information about how the bias should work, or what purpose it serves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution but should solve your problem:

```
sample = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
probability = [0.1, 0.15, 0.6, 0.05, 0.03, 0.07]
np.random.choice(a=sample, p=probability)
```

Solution 1:

```
inverse_probability = [(1-x) for x in probability]
inverse_probability = [x/sum(inverse_probability) for x in inverse_probability]
np.random.choice(a=sample, p=inverse_probability)
```

Solution 2:

```
inverse_probability = [1/x for x in probability]
inverse_probability = [x/sum(inverse_probability) for x in inverse_probability]
np.random.choice(a=sample, p=inverse_probability)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a Poisson distribution:

```
from numpy.random import poisson
index = poisson()
return sample[min(len(sample, index)]
```

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) for more details on this distribution.

Note: This is valid only if you don't have any requirements for how the prioritization is done.