# How to make an numpy array of 0 and 1 based on a probability array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I know that using Python's **random.choices** I can do this:

```
import random


array_probabilities = [0.5 for _ in range(4)]
print(array_probabilities)  # [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

a = [random.choices([0, 1], weights=[1 - probability, probability])[0] for probability in array_probabilities]
print(a)  # [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

**How to make an numpy array of 0 and 1 based on a probability array?**

Using random.choices is fast, but I know numpy is even faster. I would like to know how to write the same code but using numpy. I'm just getting started with numpy and would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Is this your answer : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018532/is-there-a-function-similar-to-np-random-choice-that-has-a-higher-probability-of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
out = (np.random.random(size=len(array_probabilities)) > array_probabilities).astype(int)
```

Example output:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If you have array = [0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9], the output should be [0, 0, 1, 1] on most iterations, but it always stays random.

Comment: Of course it's always random, but with weights. I don't see how this "*doesn't work*". Also the <0.5 probabilities are not linked. There is no reason they should have the same values.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying your solution and it gave me strange results, if p = [1, 1, 1, 1] the output was [0, 1, 0, 1] most of the times. But changing the > to < already works. Could you explain to me how that works?

Comment: How that works? Basically `np.random.random() function` generates a random number between 0 and 1 using uniform distribution. So everytime it generates a number `x,` the probability of `x < c`, where `c` is some number in `array_probabilities` vector = `c`. Hence effectively the probability of `x < c` holding True is `c`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your question got me wondering so I wrote a basic function to compare their timings. And it seems you are right! Timings change but only a little. Here you can see the code below and the output.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random
def stack_question():
    start=time.time()*1000
    array_probabilities = [0.5 for _ in range(4)]
    a = [random.choices([0, 1], weights=[1 - probability, probability])[0] for probability in array_probabilities]
    end=time.time()
    return (start-end)

def numpy_random_array():
    start_time=time.time()*1000
    val=np.random.rand(4,1)
    end_time=time.time()
    return (start_time-end_time)
print("List implementation  ",stack_question())

print("Array implementation  ",numpy_random_array())
```

The output:

```
List implementation   1665476650232.8433
Array implementation   1665476650233.9226
```

Edit: From [geeks4geeks I found the following explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-numpy-is-faster-in-python/#:%7E:text=NumPy%20Arrays%20are%20faster%20than,in%20non%2Dcontiguous%20memory%20locations.) of **why it is faster to use numpy arrays.**

*NumPy Arrays are faster than Python Lists because of the following reasons:

An array is a collection of homogeneous data-types that are stored in contiguous memory locations. On the other hand, a list in Python is a collection of heterogeneous data types stored in non-contiguous memory locations.
The NumPy package breaks down a task into multiple fragments and then processes all the fragments parallelly.
The NumPy package integrates C, C++, and Fortran codes in Python. These programming languages have very little execution time compared to Python.*

Comment: Also using numba if you have a gpu for those operations if could help if runtime is what you need!

Comment: Both are fast, but my understanding is that NumPy stays fast at larger amounts of data, while native Python doesn't.

Comment: @vanstrouble yeah you are right. I also found some explanation to this issue in geek4geeks, will update my post like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
probabilities = np.random.rand(1,10)
bools_arr = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: 1 if x > 0.5 else 0, 1, [probabilities])
```

Comment: In this case you are only evaluating that for it to be 1 it must be greater than 0.5, but it is not evaluated according to the probability criteria.

Comment: What do you mean by probability criteria?